# Getting Row Data from a list of names

Tags: r, dataframe, rows

I have this data set

```
  names age height weight
1   joe  23    170     65
2  jack  25    173     73
3   jim  27    168     71
4 james  23    172     70
```

and I want to get all the info for people under 173 height, so I do this

```
short <- c(t(subset(dfD, height < 173, select = names)))
```

`short` returns this

```
[1] "joe" "jim" "jack"
```

But when I try to get all the data from that list...

```
dfD[(dfD[1] == short),]
```

it returns only this

```
  names age height weight
1   joe  23    170     65
```

How can I get this to work?

I want to be able to create name lists and get all their data that way...how is it possible?

Comment: Will `subset()` do what you want?

Comment: Sorry, don't know what you mean, I am using `subset()` and placing the names in a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subset()` and `dlply()` will select a subset of a data frame, and change the data frame into a list. Is this what you want?

```
## Your data
df = read.table(text = "  names age height weight
  joe  23    170     65
  jack  25    173     73
  jim  27    168     71
  james  23    172     70", header = TRUE, sep = "")

  library(plyr) 
   short = subset(df, height < 173)
  data.list = dlply(short, "names")
```

OR

```
  short = subset(df, height < 173, "names")
  subset(df, names %in% short[[1]])
```

Comment: yes, this works, thanks. but I still would like to get all the data by using a list of names.

Comment: From the vector (lists are something else in R) of names you can use `subset(df, names %in% short)`